# request.session is not transferring full querydict to another view

Tags: python, django, session, view, request

I am submitting a form using 'post' and transferring its data to another view using request.POST but my querydict is incomplete when it arrives in the second view.

**view1**

```
def question_filter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('before validation', request.POST)
        request.session['question_data'] = request.POST
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('qapp:question_preview'))
```

**view2**

```
def question_preview(request):
    all_questions = Questions.objects.all()
    question_data = request.session.get('question_data')
    print(question_data)
    question_pk_list = question_data['question_pk']
    preview_questions = all_questions.filter(id__in=question_pk_list)
    ...
    return render(request,'apps/qapp/question_preview.html', {somecontext})
```

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Update:

```
before validation <QueryDict: {'topics_all': ['1', '2'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['...'], 'subtopics_all': ['4', '2'], 'classroom': ['3'], 'difficulty': ['l', 'm']}>
[28/Feb/2018 17:17:39] "POST /question/filter/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

(in the second view)question data {'topics_all': '2', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '...', 'difficulty': 'm', 'subtopics_all': '2', 'classroom': '3'}
```

Comment: can you show the printout of the post before setting it to the session

Comment: @Exprator, i have updated question with details, please have a look

Comment: The session is not saved. Look at my answer below.

Comment: For those who come across this in a search, I believe the approach from the following similar question would address this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76706665/django-managing-multi-value-post-form-fields-with-session-data-list-not-passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot send all the `post data` like that, as you have `list inside your input names,` you have to access each names differently and set them in the `session`.

```
request.session['question_data'] = request.POST.getlist('topics_all')
```

same for other `input names`, then access with key in the second view

Answer (score 0):

The session is not saved by default. Add `request.session.modified = True`:

```
def question_filter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('before validation', request.POST)
        request.session['question_data'] = request.POST
        request.session.modified = True
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('qapp:question_preview'))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved

**Edit:**

You can hack it using json:

```
import json

def question_filter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('before validation', request.POST)
        request.session['question_data'] = json.dumps(request.POST)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('qapp:question_preview'))

def question_preview(request):
    all_questions = Questions.objects.all()
    question_data = json.loads(request.session.get('question_data'))
    print(question_data)
    question_pk_list = question_data['question_pk']
    preview_questions = all_questions.filter(id__in=question_pk_list)
    ...
    return render(request,'apps/qapp/question_preview.html', {somecontext})
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it is still reaching incomplete in the second view

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat old, but as I stumbled myself because of the same issue, I want to offer a solution for those reaching this question via a search, to storing the whole `request.GET` or `request.POST` object in a session without losing data (as opposed to @Exprator’s solution which requires handling each parameter manually).

The core issue is the [default serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#session-serializer) Django uses for the session data: `django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer`. This serializer is not aware of keys associated with multiple values (for them, the `getlist()` method of `QueryDict` should be used), which results in only the last value for each key being serialized.

There are two possible solutions:

- Either manually pickle & unpickle the `request.GET` or `request.POST` object when storing & retrieving from a session;

  - This will call the `__getstate__()` method of `QueryDict`, see also an [old Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10184).
- Or, pickle the whole data of the session, by switching to the `django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer`.